# Ansible looping over sub-lists

Tags: loops, nested-loops, ansible

I have a yaml for the creation of a user.

```
 users:  
   username:  
    uid: 12345  
    gid: 6789  
    secggroups:  
         - group1  
         - group3  
    gecos: user_for_xyz  
    home: /home/username
```

I also have a file with just the `usernames` called `users_list`. The playbook to create users is as follows:

```
---  
\- name: create users
  user: name="{{ item }}" uid={{ users[item]['uid'] }} group={{ users[item][gid] }} comment="{{ users[item]['gecos'] }}" home={{ users[item]['home' }} expires=0  
  with_items:  
    \- users_list
```

How can I loop through the groups to be added to user?

Answer (score 0):

Your playbook is on the right track.

Try this for the users variable:

```
 users:  
   - username: someusername  
     uid: 12345   
     gid: 6789  
     groups:  
         - group1  
         - group3  
     gecos: "Some user"  
     home: /home/someusername  
   - username: someusername  
     ... etc ...
```

And this for the user play

```
- name: User creation
  user: 
    name:"{{item.username}}"
    groups: "{{item.groups | join(',')}}"
    comment: "{{item.name}}"
    uid: "{{item.uid}}"
  with_items: users
```

Note that I modified your syntax to not use inline YAML.

Also you may find [this users role](https://github.com/mivok/ansible-users) helpful.

Comment: There was an error in the example like gecos is not supported in the ansible user module instead it is comment plus there was  an error, like it should be gecos instead of name inside the comment value. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this using subelements like this:

```
- name: User creation
   user:
    name:"{{item.0.username}}"
    groups: "{{item.1 }}"
  with_subelements:
    - "{{ users }}"
    - groups
```

here is a sample to debug, like a directory tree:

```
vars:
  test:
    - name: Testing subelements loop
      dir: dir0

      subdir:
        - subdir0
        - subdir1
        - subdir2
tasks:
  - name: Subelements loop sample
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item.0.dir }}/{{ item.1 }}"
    with_subelements:
      - "{{ test }}"
      - subdir
```

you can find more here: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html#standard-loops